# Negative voltage at the output of non-inverting opamp

Tags: voltage, thermocouple

I want to amplify the output voltage of a thermocouple by using a two-stage operational amplifier but the output that I get is a negative voltage at or below room temperature(<=30 degree Celsius). I get a positive voltage at the output of the amplifier when the thermocouple is heated to 200 degrees or more.[image: Image is a screenshot of my proteus simulation circuit. I have implemented the same circuit practically]

I am facing another problem now. The outputs of both the opamps are showing -3.4 Volts. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you should lower your reference voltage (inverting pin of amplifier)

Comment: What output voltage range are you expecting?  In other words, what transfer function do you desire?

Comment: Note also that I don't see any cold-junction compensation in your circuit.

Comment: For cold junction compensation, I shall use a temperature sensor to sense the ambient temperature, calculate the voltage equivalent to the ambient temperature, then add this voltage to the output voltage of the amplifier and finally calculate the temperature for this voltage , which will give me the thermocouple temperature

Comment: I am expecting an output voltage greater than 0 volts ranging to the saturation voltage of op07 (around 4 volts). Input to the amplifier from thermocouple is in millivolts range and I am using an amplifier of practical gain around 160

Comment: How can I lower reference voltage here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your cold junction is cooler than the hot one, when this type of problem occurs, it is usually time to get the oscilloscope out and look for instability in your op-amps, especially if you measure a small voltage across the input pins & the o/p is not saturated and a new op-amp reads the same.
Put some 0.1uF decoupling capacitors (monolithic type preferred) across your + & - supplies near the amplifiers. Feedback through the supplies is the most likely cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit is responding to what thermocouples do.

When the temperature at the junction is less than the temperature at the so-called cold junction(s) (CJ) (where the two thermocouple metals are connected to copper) the voltage from the thermocouple is negative. If it is hotter, then the voltage is positive. In both cases, for most base-metal thermocouples, it's roughly linear around room temperature.

If you want it to read something equivalent to 0V at 0°C you need to bias the amplifier positive by a small amount, however that will introduce an error of 1°C for every 1°C the room temperature changes. The old-school way to deal with that is to approximate the slope of voltage change of the thermocouple with another temperature sensor located at the aforementioned junctions to compensate. This is called cold-junction compensation. In modern instrumentation we often find the nonlinearity unacceptable and measure the temperature precisely as before, but apply an inverse linearization curve (to get mV from temperature) and then add that to the voltage from the thermocouple before applying a forward linearization curve to get temperature from voltage.

In the **really** old-school the cold junctions would be immersed in an ice-water slurry which would give a fairly good 0°C reference (as long as you keep the ice and water present) and then the mV output from the copper leads would be directly related to the temperature above or below 0°C, with very close to 0mV out at 0°C at the "hot" junction.

Comment: I have used the NIST equations to calculate temperature from voltage. The only point where I was struggling was in setting the gain of my amplifier in my software program. I was getting output voltage (Vo) of amplifier from the adc value of microcontroller and from that I was calculating the input voltage to the amplifier (output voltage from thermocouple) by dividing Vo by the gain value. Accurate gain value gives you the accurate input voltage and thus shows the accurate temperature

Comment: The NIST equations assume a cold junction temperature of 0°C. The circuit you show will only be able to read correctly if you control the cold junction(s) at 0°C.

Comment: For cold junction compensation, I shall use a temperature sensor to sense the ambient temperature, calculate the voltage equivalent to the ambient temperature, then add this voltage to the output voltage of the amplifier and finally calculate the temperature for this voltage, which will give me the thermocouple temperature.Here is the link I have used for calculation: http://www.mosaic-industries.com/embedded-systems/microcontroller-projects/temperature-measurement/thermocouple/type-k-calibration-table.Instead of maintaining cold junction 0 degree, I have calculated the cold junction voltage.